# Mantic Minotaur Upgrade - Touchpad stops working

Tags: touchpad, 23.10

Just upgraded to 23.10 Mantic Minotaur and everything seems to work except my touchpad. Luckily I have a bluetooth mouse that is working. I've searched for solutions. None of the easy solutions have worked yet. I have an elan touchpad. I also tried to open a virtual terminal but using Ctrl+Alt+1-6 does not open it to debug. Is anyone else with elan experiencing this and has a solution? The touchpad does not show up in xinput.

`cat proc/bus/input/devices` gives this for touchpad:

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=0007 Version=0000
N: Name="Elan Touchpad"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-ELAN0000:00/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event7 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=663800013000003
```

`xinput` gives this output:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:15              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```